# YouTube Data API audit - how to track status

Tags: youtube-data-api

At my company we use the YouTube Data API for a couple of tools.  I received a notice that I needed to fill out an audit form.  As part of that form, it asked for a demo username and password, but our tools don't support a level of access that I'd be comfortable giving anyone outside our company.  There was also a place to upload screencasts so I did that instead, and explained why I was not providing demo credentials.  So far, so good.  But two days after I submitted the form, I got another email with a "third and final notice" about submitting the audit form.  I am unable to tell if my submission got lost, if it just hasn't been reviewed yet, or if it was deemed inadequate.  I sent emails to some support emails but they suggested that I go here on Stack Overflow.